# Question about a Lego Compatible brand with "B L" logo

Tags: building, 3rd-party, clone-brands

My son has a small orange and grey space ship building set. It has two astronauts with it. The logo on the bricks shows the letters "B L" on them. We're trying to find instructions online so that he can put it back together. I'm not familiar with this brand and I have no idea where the gift was purchased. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

My guess is:

bestlock construction bricks, a inferior lego clone brand

[Best-lock](http://www.best-lock.com/)

logo should be this
[image: Logo]

the only grey and orange set i found
[image]
[Space ship](http://www.play.com/Toys/Toys/-/3501/2768/-/13027973/Best-Lock-Spaceship-Construction-Play-Set/Product.html)

couldn't find the instructions

Answer (score 5):

Could it be this one?

[image]

http://web.archive.org/web/20160410154631/http://commandercottontail.com/index.php/blog/get_post?id=12

If so, I included some photos of the instructions about halfway down in that review.